# To calculate a new column with three tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have **3 input tables** as :

```
    **Student Table**     
    -------------
    id    name
    -------------
    201     shiva
    202     Jitendra
    203     Makarand
    204     Arpit

    **Position Table**
    -------------
    id    rank
    -------------
    203    1
    201    2
    202    3
    204    4

    **House Table**
    ------------------
    housename    id
    ------------------
    Yellow        201
    Blue          202
    Red           203
    Yellow        204
```

There are n-records in student Table

I want to calculate points(column) with formula P = sum(n+1 - rank)*100

```
    ** Output Table **
-------------------------------
HouseName      Name      Points
-------------------------------
yellow         Shiva         300
Red            Makarand      200
Yellow         Arpit         100
```

I have written this query:

```
select h.housename "House Name",
       s.name "Name",
       (sum ( (count(*) from s + 1) - p.rank ) ) * 100 as "Points"
       from House h,Student s,Position p
       where h.housename = (select s.name where s.id = h.id)
       order by Points
```

Sample SQL Fiddle is here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d823/26

I am newbie to SQL, how can I get this query correct?

Comment: n is the number of students ?

Comment: @scaisEdge Yes, n = number of students in student table

Comment: Which are the relations between the 3 tables .? .looking to your sample is not clear ..

Comment: @scaisEdge Id is common in all 3- tables ,so problem is to calculate points column with above formula

Comment: But id      201 Student ALI, Table position 2 House yellow ... your result ali blue ..... is not so clear for me .. a

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, if you are trying to get the Points(using the formula) from three tables,

```
 select h.housename "House Name",
   s.name "Name",
   ((count(s.id) + 1 - p.rank ) * 100) as "Points"
   from House h join Student s on s.id = h.id join Position p on p.id=s.id order by Points
```

I didn't run this query. Could you check and confirm?

Comment: Yes going right, but the above query has errors. [link] http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d823/26